# How to perform recursive delete using glob pattern in a directory using python?

Tags: python, delete-file

```
DirA
  file1.txt
  file2.conf
  DirB
      file3.txt
      file4.sh
      file5.sh
      DirC
          file6.bat
          file7.txt
```

In above example dir I need to perform recursive delete with glob pattern.

```
pattern = ['*,txt','*.sh']
```

Using the above pattern I need to delete all the files with *.txt and *.sh formats in all the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, glob

pattern = ['*.txt', '*.sh']

for p in pattern:
    [os.remove(x) for x in glob.iglob('DirA/**/' + p, recursive=True)]
```

If you want you can use list comprehensions to do this task. Cya!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('DirA/**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.iglob('DirA/**/*.sh', recursive=True):
    os.remove(filename)
```

This should work to delete all txt and sh files in the directory recursively.

Or if you want to specify an array with patterns:

```
import os
import glob


def removeAll(pathToDir, patterns):
    for pattern in patterns:
        for filename in glob.iglob(pathToDir + '/**/' + pattern, recursive=True):
            os.remove(filename)


patterns = ['*.txt', '*.sh']

removeAll('DirA', patterns)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.walk` instead so that you only need to traverse the directories once. With `glob` you would have to traverse twice since you have two patterns to look for.

```
import os
for root, _, files in os.walk('DirA'):
    for file in files:
        if any(file.endswith(ext) for ext in pattern):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Instead of .endswith can we use glob pattern? Because the patterns are passed as a parameter

Comment: glob pattern is a simplified version of regex. You can test the file name with a regex pattern if you have a more complex file pattern that can't be tested with the `endswith` method; otherwise the `endswith` method is more efficient.

Comment: Assuming none of your files have extraneous `.` you could also use `if file.split('.')[1] in patterns`. This will allow you to compare to `patterns` list

Comment: I've updated my answer to make use of the `pattern` list.